# Copy and rename the new file using BAT command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a file in `C:\` folder which is the following:

```
My_File_mmddyyyy_hhmmss.txt
```

The file's `mmddyy_hhmmss` will change based on the date and time the file is generated. How can I create a batch file which will copy that file to `C:\TEST\` and rename the copied file to `My_File_mmddyy.txt` (drop the `_hhmmss` from the file name)?

since the date and time changes in the filename, can I do something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
xcopy /s c:\My_File_*.txt c:\TEST\My_File_mmddyyyy.txt
```

But then the original `mmddyyyy` will disappear.

How can I achieve what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `COPY` (among others) has this bit of little-known functionality:

```
COPY My_File_*.txt My_File_????????.txt
```

The eight question marks in the new name will result in the `mmddyyyy` part of the source being exactly preserved.

Comment: the mmddyy are actually auto generated number from the system so it can be anything at any time... Hence I would like that to be used with a wildcard... the `My_File_` is always the same

Comment: @SiKni8: That's not a problem because you can always use `FOR` to capture the file name even if you don't know it. But in this case even that is not necessary; just use a wildcard for the source file. I updated the answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I had `s` which caused the batch to not work.